# How to call an overloaded function when you only have a variable conforming to a lesser type?

Tags: swift

Is there a way for Swift to correctly infer which overloaded function to call given a variable that conforms to a common protocol of each of the overloaded parameters?

In the code example below, I want to be able to pass a generic object of type `Command` to a number of other objects that might be able to process it.

However, the type information is "lost" when an object is downcast to the base protocol. This prevents me from being able to use function overloading based on the type of the command.

Is there a way to get that type information "back" so that Swift has enough information to correctly call the appropriate function?

```
protocol Command {}
protocol ToDoCommand : Command {}
protocol UserCommand : Command {}

struct AddToDoCommand  : ToDoCommand {}
struct EditToDoCommand : ToDoCommand {}

struct AddUserCommand  : UserCommand {}
struct EditUserCommand : UserCommand {}

class ToDoManager {
  func performCommand(_ command:Command) {
    guard let todoCommand = command as? ToDoCommand else {
      return
    }

    // Perform some tasks that are common to all ToDoCommands...

    // This produces a compiler error because 'todoCommand' is of 
    // type ToDoCommand, which is not specific enough for Swift
    // to deduce which overloaded function to call. Can this
    // be overcome?

    performToDoCommand(todoCommand)
  }

  func performToDoCommand(_ command:AddToDoCommand) {
    print("Add ToDo")
  }

  func performToDoCommand(_ command:EditToDoCommand) {
    print("Edit ToDo")
  }
}

class UserManager {
  func performCommand(_ command:Command) {
    guard let userCommand = command as? UserCommand else {
      return
    }

    // Perform some tasks that are common to all UserCommands...

    // See note above...
    performUserCommand(userCommand)
  }

  func performUserCommand(_ command:AddUserCommand) {
    print("Add User")
  }

  func performUserCommand(_ command:EditUserCommand) {
    print("Edit User")
  }

}

let todoManager = ToDoManager()
let userManager = UserManager()

let command = AddUserCommand()
todoManager.performCommand(command)
userManager.performCommand(command)
```

Comment: You can eliminate the error by adding `func performToDoCommand(_ command:Command) { print("base") }` and `func performUserCommand(_ command:Command) { print("base") }` but then only those are called and not the more specific methods.

Comment: Right, but then I'm still left with having to determine what type of ToDo or User command it is, presumably with a giant `switch` statement, which is what I was hoping to avoid by using function overloading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to go about this...

**Use a `switch` to reestablish the type**

Swift needs to know at *compile time* which overloaded function it is calling.  This can't happen if Swift doesn't know at compile time which type of the variable it has.

To get the type information back, you can use a `switch` to reestablish the type:

```
func performCommand(_ command:Command) {
    guard let todoCommand = command as? ToDoCommand else {
        return
    }

    // Perform some tasks that are common to all ToDoCommands...

    switch todoCommand {
    case let command as AddToDoCommand:
        performCommand(command)
    case let command as EditToDoCommand:
        performCommand(command)
    default: break
    }
}
```

---

**Use polymorphism**

A way to let Swift decide which `performToDoCommand()` command to run at runtime is to use *polymorphism*.

Add the requirement to implement `func performToDoCommand()` to the `ToDoCommand` protocol, and then implement that for each `struct` that conforms to `ToDoCommand`.  Calling the right one is then simple...

```
protocol Command {}
protocol ToDoCommand : Command {
    func performToDoCommand()
}
protocol UserCommand : Command {}

struct AddToDoCommand  : ToDoCommand {
    func performToDoCommand() {
        print("Add ToDo")
    }
}

struct EditToDoCommand : ToDoCommand {
    func performToDoCommand() {
        print("Edit ToDo")
    }
}

struct AddUserCommand  : UserCommand {}
struct EditUserCommand : UserCommand {}

class ToDoManager {
    func performCommand(_ command:Command) {
        guard let todoCommand = command as? ToDoCommand else {
            return
        }

        todoCommand.performToDoCommand()
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot that I can use switch like that. However, a giant switch statement was exactly what I was trying to avoid by using function overloading. I currently use an `enum` with associated values to represent a `Command` but wanted to switch over to using a `struct` for a bit more flexibility. The `enum` naturally works with a giant switch statement but felt a little redundant with structs.

Comment: See edit.  What about using polymorphism to call the different functions.

Comment: A viable option and one I'm considering, thank you. My biggest issue with this is that it moves the logic out of the `ToDoManager` class. I would like to reach the point where each of these commands could be executed within such isolation, but I don't think I'm there yet. (And least not without a lot of other changes.) `performToDoCommand()` would have to take numerous `inout` parameters to be able to modify the internals of `ToDoManager`. But maybe that needs to be cleaned up anyways...

Answer (score 2):

I think you're trying to recreate class inheritance. Instead, you want composition. You've created a bunch of empty protocols that are acting like abstract classes. That's not the right way to think about protocols. I think what you want are just structs.

```
// A command is just something that can be performed
struct Command {
    let perform: () -> Void
}

// And there are lots of ways to make them
extension Command {
    // We can make command types that wrap other command types
    static func makeToDo(additional: @escaping () -> Void) -> Command {
        return Command {
            // common todo behavior
            additional()
        }
    }
}

// And we can just make regular commands
extension Command {
    // Things that include ToDo
    static func makeAddToDo() -> Command { makeToDo { print("Add ToDo") } }
    static func makeEditToDo() -> Command { makeToDo { print("Edit ToDo") }}
    // Things that don't
    static func makeAddUser() -> Command { Command{print("Add User")}}
    static func makeEditUser() -> Command { Command{print("Edit User")}}
}
```

There is now no reason for a UserManager that ignores things sent to it or a ToDoManager that ignores things sent to it. Those are really confusing ways to do this. "Here's a command. Please perform it if you know how, but ignore it if you don't." What are you supposed to do if none of the managers know how to perform the command? Or multiple managers?

Instead, you just create a bunch of commands and then call `.perform()`.

Comment: Thanks Rob, always appreciate the comments. In the current architecture, the commands require a bit more context to be performed. The commands are initiated from UI events and don't have enough context at the time they are triggered to create a closure with enough information. The "managers" fill in the blanks, do some house keeping and make sure the models are properly updated. I wish there was better isolation, but there isn't at the moment. This architecture is *very* loosely based on the Flux pattern, so it's OK if managers just ignore commands they don't support.

Comment: If the point is that the managers interpret the context for the commands, turn the world around. Pass the manager to the command when it's created. Then, when the command is executed, it can ask its manager to provided the required context and preform any required housekeeping. (Trying to solve this with `as?` casting and overloads is going to be insanely fragile, even if you get this working. You need a solution that doesn't rely on that.)

Comment: Agreed that using `as?` and overloads is probably not the best solution. Passing the manager to the command requires that the manager be accessible wherever these commands are created, which isn't always the case. Commands can be triggered from lots of places: menu items, TouchBar, keyboard shortcuts, Toolbar, etc. Each of those places can send an asynchronous "command" through a central dispatcher. The command might be processed locally, by a "manager", or might get sent to a child process via XPC.

Comment: In that case you want your commands to be pure data and dumber. In particular if they're going to be passed over XPC. Rather than classes, I'd give them identifiers and statically register the identifiers with a dispatcher. I might even encode them all the way to `Data` using `JSONEncoder` to give a common currency that various managers could decode and that could be transmitted in a pure form.

Comment: The key to highly generic code is finding common currencies, like `Data` or `URLRequest` or even some kind of generic "Command" can encode *anything*. Then you can build pipelines that traffic in that common currency, only deserializing at the endpoint. But if XPC is actually involved here, `as?` casting is definitely the wrong road. The best way to find how to make this generic is to start by building it *not* generic. Let the code duplicate & work in concrete types. Then look for where the duplications really happen and extract those into generic code. Avoid systems that are "generic-first."

Comment: The current implementation leverages Obj-C's dynamic typing but places a burden on some parts of the code that need to specificallycast to a known class. Serialization, when necessary, is done using `NSSecureCoding`. As I look to transition this to Swift, I've been exploring ways to make it more type-safe while maintaining some degree of flexibility that I get from the ObjC implementation. There might not be a perfect solution but I do strongly lead towards a design where the "commands" are really just descriptors that carry some level of type information with them, as you've stated.